# combining two streams, pulling element from one then other

Tags: sml

Given these declarations I am having trouble understanding streams in SML:

```
exception Bad of string;
fun from seed next = Cons(seed,fn () => from (next seed) next);
fun head (Nil) = raise Bad("got nil in head")
    | head (Cons(a,b)) = a;

fun tail (Nil) = raise Bad("got nil in tail") 
    | tail(Cons(a,b)) = b();

fun take 0 stream = nil
    | take n (Nil) = raise Bad("got nil in take")
    |take n (Cons(h,t)) = h::(take (n-1) (t()));
```

I can create a stream of naturals [1.0,2.0,3.0...] like so: `val nat = from 1.0 (fn x => x+1.0);`

and a stream of ones: `val one = from 1.0 (fn x => x);`

But how would i go about creating a stream from these two streams? Specifically a function that merges two streams and outputs a stream.

something like: `fun merge a b` where a and b are streams. Ie if we did `take 5` after merging these two it would give [1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0,3.0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this were a list, you would write

```
fun merge a b = Cons (head a, Cons (head b, merge (tail a) (tail b)))
```

and then you add a function indirection to each cons to "streamify" it:

```
fun merge a b = Cons (head a, fn () => Cons (head b, fn () => (merge (tail a) (tail b))))
```